# Adding geom_abline to residual vs fitted data from glm using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I have my data that looks like this:

```
y = c(12, 14, 33, 50, 67, 74, 123, 141, 165, 204, 253, 246, 240)
t = 1:13
aids.pois <- glm(y~t, data=data, family="poisson")
cc <- data.frame(aids.pois$residuals, aids.pois$fitted.values)
```

I wanted to add geom_abline to the plot below, but couldn't show the abline:

```
ggplot(cc, aes(x = aids.pois.fitted.values, y = aids.pois.residuals)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline()
```

I am expecting something like this (but using ggplot)

```
plot(aids.pois, which = 1, main = "base R: Residual Vs fitted plot")
```

[image]

Comment: `geom_abline` is only for lines of the form y = mx + b, I think `geom_smooth` might give what you want

Comment: @DiceboyT Is it possible to get it without smooth? I just wanted to replicate the base R plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something similar to what the base `plot()` is doing, you can do this

```
cc <- data.frame(resid=resid(aids.pois), fitted=fitted(aids.pois))

ggplot(cc, aes(x = fitted, y = resid)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", color="red", se=FALSE) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype=2, color="darkgrey") +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

The red line from `plot()` is just a loess smoothing of the plotted points. You can add the reference line with `geom_hline`. No need for `geom_abline` here at all.